# What is the proper syntax for using a django template variable as a jade href id reference?

Tags: django, pug

I am trying to generate a navigation table using a django template `for` loop.  The href target includes a django variable.  The django template is written in jade format.

If i were using HTML format in the django template, I would use:

```
<a href="#{{group.name}}"> {{group.name}} </a>
```

But I can't find the correct syntax using jade format.

What I have is:

```
table.generic
  tbody
    tr
      th Jump to a Group
    {% for group in groups %}
    tr
      td
        a(href!='#{{group.name}}') {{group.name}}
    {% endfor %}
```

But the anchors are rendered in HTML as:

```
<a +{group.name.__str__()+'}'="" href="">Registration</a>
```

"Registration" is a value for group.name.

Removing the `!` causes a django render error.

I tried to insert a backslash: `a(href!='#\{{group.name}}') {{group.name}}`, but this renders with the backslash intact as:

```
<a href="#\Registration">Registration</a>
```

Suggestions?

**Edit:** As a terrible work-around, I have added a "pound" method to return the group name with a `#` prefix:

```
def pound(self): 
    return unicode("#" + self.name)
```

Now I can reference {{group.pound}} in the jade template:

```
a(href!='{{group.pound}}') {{group.name}}
```

Maybe a better method name would be group.name_as_id_tag ....

---

### RESOLVED: Format the django template variable as a jade variable

Based on the last suggestion from @user1737909, I extended the suggestion to try:

```
a(href='##{group.name}') {{group.name}}
```

The key is to format the double-curly django variable `{{}}` as pound-single-curly jade variable `#{}`.  Do not include the `!` before the `=` sign so the variable *is* evaluated by jade which will insert the value it gets from django.

I wish I could find a link to a coding style reference page to include here.  But if I had one, I would not have asked this question in the first place.

Comment: any particular reason your rendering out to jade templates with django?

Comment: Current syntax issue aside, I find the format faster and cleaner not having to focus on `<`, `>`, and closing tags.

Comment: Have you tried [pyjade](https://github.com/SyrusAkbary/pyjade) ?

Comment: for the `#` problem, jade sees it as interp, you can try `'#'+'{{foo}}'` (or maybe `#\{{abc}`)

Comment: @user1737909: I am using pyjade-1.6-py2.7.  Also, it seems inserting a `+` or a backslash or any char yields `#+Registration` or `#\Registration` or `#charRegistration`.

Comment: @user1737909: `a(href!='#' + '{{foo}}')` yields `<a 'registration'="" +="" href="#"></a>`.

Comment: Try `a(href!="##{foo}")`

Comment: @user1737909: your last suggestion was very close. It prompted me to try it with out the `!`.  The solution seems to be `a(href='##{foo}')`.  Remarking the OP with this solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the last suggestion from @user1737909, I extended the suggestion to try:

```
a(href='##{group.name}') {{group.name}}
```

The key is to format the double-curly django variable `{{}}` as pound-single-curly jade variable `#{}`. Do not include the `!` before the `=` sign so the variable is evaluated by jade which will insert the value it gets from django.

OP updated to reflect this solution.